# ¿Qué es "choclo" en el rioplatense de Rosario, Argentina?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, argentina

Leyendo [el perfil de nuestro insigne usuario argentino pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76?tab=profile) me encontré con un párrafo muy sugestivo para mí, que estoy en el otro lado del océano:

> Nacido, criado y viviendo en Rosario, provincia de Santa Fe, región litoral de Argentina, 300 km antes de que el río Paraná se vuelque al océano. Dialecto rioplatense con eses tan aspiradas que ya ni aliento les queda. **Digo *poroto*, *pimiento*, *choclo*, *pororó*, *costeleta* y *praliné***. Hablo inglés, portugués brasileño, cachitos de japonés y de alemán.

Algunas de las palabras las conozco, pero supuse que si las menciona es porque su uso dialectal es diferente del estándar.

En particular, me gustó *choclo*. El DRAE incluye tres entradas:
http://dle.rae.es/?id=8wiBgJJ|8wku5re

> **choclo**<sup>1</sup>
>   `Del lat. soccŭlus.`
>   1. m. chanclo (‖ sandalia de madera o suela gruesa).
>
> **choclo**<sup>2</sup>
>   `Del quechua choccllo.`
>   1. m. Arg., Bol., Chile, Col., Ec., Par. y Perú. Mazorca tierna de maíz.
>   2. m. Arg. y Col. humita (‖ comida criolla).

Y luego el DAMER dice:

> [**choclo**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=GAlycWG7Cx0AquBNvD9). (`Del quech. chuqllu, mazorca de maíz`).
>   I.  1.  m. Co:O,SO, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar, Ur. Mazorca tierna de maíz.
>   2.  Ec, Ch, Py. Maíz tierno desgranado, crudo o cocido.
>   II. 1.  m. Ar. Cosa que resulta larga o pesada, especialmente un discurso o una materia de estudio. pop.
>   2.  Ur. Relato exagerado o falso de un hecho. pop.
>   III.    1.  m. Ar. Cantidad grande de algo. pop.
>   IV. 1.  m. Ec. p.u. Diente de una persona.
>   V.  1.  Pa. chocolón, hoyuelo.
>   ▶   desgranar el ~; estar ~.

Me quedo especialmente con la entrada propia de Argentina: _II. 1.  m. Ar. Cosa que resulta larga o pesada, especialmente un discurso o una materia de estudio. pop. _.

Entonces, ¿a qué se refiere el uso dialectal de *choclo* en Rosario, Argentina?

<sub>(Lógicamente estaréis pensando que por qué narices no le pregunta a Pablo directamente. Bueno, [lo hice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28279/does-preguntar-need-a-pronoun-in-spanish/28335#comment49091_28335), pero así lo aprendemos todos :) )</sub>

Comment: En Chile también puedes usar"choclo" para "problema" o "asunto largo y pesado", aunque está quedando en desuso. Los dientes son los choclos o "chocleros".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mi mención de *choclo*, como las de las otras palabras, tiene que ver con delimitar mi dialecto (cosa que no suele importar mucho pero sí importa en este foro). La palabra *choclo* para designar a la mazorca de maíz tiene, como se ve, una distribución que sigue aproximadamente la antigua esfera de influencia del imperio inca o Tawantinsuyu, cuya capital estaba en Cuzco, Perú. Ni Paraguay ni Uruguay fueron nunca parte de este imperio pero evidentemente la palabra llegó allí por difusión de zonas cercanas. En esta región tuvo mucha influencia léxica el tupí-guaraní (que hasta hoy es lengua co-oficial en Paraguay) y los nativos cultivaban el maíz, pero las palabras que usaban para designarlo no pasaron al castellano.

En mi dialecto rioplatense local (y quizá en otros), además de significar "mazorca de maíz", *un choclo* es, como dice el DLE, una materia de estudio muy densa o un discurso largo y pesado (a veces en aumentativo: *un choclazo*). Este uso probablemente se esté perdiendo en las nuevas generaciones, a las cuales, ay, no pertenezco. No conozco el origen de este significado. Si se trata de cosas escritas, este *choclo* parece similar (y suena también muy parecido) a *tocho*, que por lo que veo se usa en España y refiere a una pila grande de papeles o a un libro muy grande y pesado.

Decir que digo *choclo* no delimita demasiado mi región, ya que es el uso habitual en casi todo el Cono Sur. Otras palabras hacen ese trabajo: por ejemplo, al marcar que digo *pororó* (palabra de origen guaraní) me coloco al norte de una línea imaginaria que me separa de los hablantes rioplatenses (como los de Buenos Aires) que dicen mayoritariamente *pochoclo* (palabra construida sobre la base del quechua *choclo*). El pororó o pochoclo son palomitas de maíz; *pochoclo* refiere al maíz, mientras que *pororó* remite al ruido que producen los granos de maíz al estallar (de ahí proviene también la palabra *[pororoca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pororoca)*).

Comment: _Tostón, muermo, rollo_... cuántas palabras para el mismo concepto. :-)

Comment: !Holla! Viviendo y aprendiendo... Mucho me gustó su explicación. Yo estuve en Córdoba en setiembre y cuando my guía turístico se refirió al maizal, yo le dice que en Brasil és milho. Ahora vos trae eses muchos conceptos. Que bueno. Así que vamos siguiendo con nuestro aprendizado por la vida... El maiz o choclo o milho és un grano muy hermoso y en algunas regiónes los hay de muchas colores. Su signicado (supe ahora) és " el que sostiene la vida" !Que bello! Gracias.